# How can I make an Alert appear in the screen using AG Grid and Adaptable/

Tags: ag-grid, rxjs5, rxjs6, ag-grid-react, rxjs-observables

I created an Observable Alert in AG Grid (using Adaptable) which is correctly firing when an order is stale for 2 minutes.
But I only see the Alert in the Toolbar and not as a popup notification in the grid like happens in this demo: https://demo.adaptabletools.com/alertsmessages/aggridobservablealertdemo

The Expression for the Alert is

```
GRID_CHANGE( [order_tick] ), TIMEFRAME('2m') )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say in your question if you are providing the Alert at run-time or design-time.

If the latter then in your Alert Predefined Config definition you need to set 'DisplayNotification' to true in the `AlertProperties` section:

```
 AlertProperties: {
   DisplayNotification: true,
 }
```

If you are creating it at run-time then in the 3 step of the Wizard ('Type and Display'), you need to enable the checkbox: 'Show a Notification when Alert is triggered'.